# How to implement searchview in android and list out the data from the database

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application that has a search box, I need to display all the data from the array list in the search box when searching.The data is actually coming after calling a webservice and can able to store the data in an arraylist called outputdatalist.

**This is the search.xml:**

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:hint="Search by salon name"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_logo"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/search_logo"/>
```

Java file contains the array with all the data's. Here is an example of the list, the array contain the data.

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(var1);
     Log.i("jsonObjectttttttttttt", jsonObject.toString());
     JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data")
     Log.i("jsonObjecttttttt1", jsonObject1.toString());
     JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("results");
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject child = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            outputDataList.add(child.getString("name"));
            Log.i("salonn names",outputDataList.toString());}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider looking at the developer guide on Android. It provides a good sample on how you can achieve what you want to do.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

It is similar to an **EditText** and **ListView**, close to what you are trying to implement. 
It has a detailed explanation of what steps to do.

When you receive data (in JSON form) you will require a parser that reads out the data and form it add it into a data object (eg. ArrayList) which will be passed into the adapter to bind with the ListView.

Hope this help you understand what you need to achieve. Cheers!